# How to identify infected ELF files

Tags: virus, elf

For my coursework, I have written a simple virus program which copies itself to ANY ONE ELF (except the virus itself) file in the current directory.

Now when the infected ELF file is run, it should infect ONE other (non-infected) ELF file (if present).

However I am having problem in adding this functionality in my virus program. How can the virus code identify if an ELF is already infected or not.

Is there any `field` in `ELF` file where I can store this information ? Or any other way ?

Comment: The question I have is that, since you wrote the virus, wouldn't you have the signature of your own virus and its location? I would imagine that putting these thing in some ELF field wouldn't be the best way to do since you are make it wide open for anti-virus inspection?

Comment: the "modified" date of the file will have changed

Comment: please call it the krampus virus. I beg you. Also I would be very interested in how you did this? is this a self executable virus? or just a program you wrote that adds it self, I would be very interested in learning how to do this